# Create a view in SQLite3 that lists all unique paths through tree-like database structure

Tags: view, sqlite, sql-view

I'm using SQLite3 (and python, but that's not important for the question, I don't think) to build a database of parts in a hierarchical assembly with multiple nesting levels, where every part in the assembly can have multiple variants. The database can include entries from multiple assemblies which might have varying numbers of member parts. I have a table with an entry for every unique part that has a column for the part ID, a column for the assembly ID, and a column for the ID of the parent part in the assembly hierarchy (if any). Additionally, I have a second table that lists unique variations on all of the parts with columns for the part properties and a column for the ID number of the assembly part that the entry is a variation of.

I would like to be able to build a list of every possibly unique variation of an *assembly*. Is it possible to do this as a view within the SQLite database, and if so, how would I structure that query? Or is there a way that I can structure my database differently to make this task easier?

EDIT:
Sample structure:

```
Table: "PARTS"
PART_ID  PART_NAME   PARENT  ASSEMBLY
1        'Foo'       NULL    1
2        'Bar'       1       1
3        'Thing'     1       1
4        'Doodad'    1       1
5        'Bauble'    3       1
6        'Oof'       NULL    2
7        'Rab'       6       2
8        'Trinket'   6       2

Table: "VARIATIONS"
VAR_ID   PART_ID    PROPERTY_1   PROPERTY_2   PROPERTY_3
1        1          3.14159      0.63         0
2        1          3.24359      0.68         1
3        1          3            0.5          0.9999999
4        2          0.1          0.1          0.1
5        3          0.11         0.01         0.0005
6        3          0.11         0.01         0.0006
7        4          0.05         0.05         0.05
8        5          0.001        0.08         0.001
9        5          0.001        0.085        0.0011
10       6          5.5          1.0          3.2
11       7          1.1          0.99         1.2
12       8          0.05         0.05         0.05
```

I would like to list all possible combinations of variations parts in the assembly, which would look like this for parts in Assembly 1 from the table above. The columns below are the VAR_ID's from the VARIATIONS table for the respective part numbers.

```
ROWNUM   PART1_VAR  PART2_VAR  PART3_VAR  PART4_VAR PART5_VAR
1        1          4          5          7         8
2        2          4          5          7         8
3        3          4          5          7         8
4        1          4          6          7         8
5        2          4          6          7         8
6        3          4          6          7         8
7        1          4          5          7         9
8        2          4          5          7         9
9        3          4          5          7         9
10       1          4          6          7         9
11       2          4          6          7         9
12       3          4          6          7         9
```

Comment: On the face of it [WITH RECURSIVE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) is the place to start. It is difficult for me to answer how to structure the query or the database without seeing sample data and expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That looks like it's the right place to start. I've added an example table structure and output structure to the question. I'm a complete n00b at databases, so I'm not sure if that particular structure of output is even possible, but I think it gets across the kind of output I'm looking for.

Comment: The example clarifies, thank you. And I retract WITH RECURSIVE. The obstacle here  is variable number of columns (assembly 1 will have 5; assembly 2 will have 3). IME, sql isn't the tool for that. Perhaps python is significant.Select the cartesian product of parts/variations then build the desired array in python? Just typing out loud.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to this project after a long hiatus and got it working by manually building queries on the fly in python. It is in fact not possible, as @DinoCoderSaurus pointed out, to create a single table listing the variations of all assemblies in the example, but I was able to create a separate table of assembly variations for each assembly.

The python code that should work with the example in the question looks like this. It's not elegant, but it works.

```
assembly = 1
          
#List fragments from current assembly in hierarchical order
query = f'''
    WITH RECURSIVE
        hierarchy(PART,LEVEL) AS (
        VALUES('',0)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT PARTS.PART_ID, hierarchy.LEVEL+1
            FROM PARTS JOIN hierarchy ON PARTS.PARENT=hierarchy.FRAGMENT
            WHERE PARTS.ASSEMBLY={assembly}
            ORDER BY 2
        )
        SELECT PART FROM hierarchy;
    '''
parts = [qq[0] for qq in cursor.execute(query).fetchall()[1:]]
# Create SQL-friendly column names from the list of part IDs
colnames = [f'PART_{qq}' for qq in parts]
# Generate a dictionary of parent parts for each part
parents = {f'PART_{c}':f'PART_{p}' for c,p in self.query('SELECT PART_ID,PARENT FROM PARTS')}

# Generate a long query of as many successive join statements between temporary 
# tables as it takes to traverse the assembly hierarchy tree, deleting each 
# previous temporary table as you go.
joins = '\n'.join([f"""
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_table_{ii:d}({' TEXT, '.join(colnames[:ii+1])} TEXT); 
    INSERT INTO new_table_{ii:d}  
        SELECT new_table_{ii-1:d}.*, VAR_ID 
            FROM new_table_{ii-1:d} 
                INNER JOIN VARIATIONS 
                        ON PARENT_VAR=new_table_{ii-1:d}.{parents[colnames[ii]]} 
                            AND PART_ID = '{fragments[ii]}';
    DROP TABLE new_table_{ii-1:d};""" for ii in range(1,len(colnames))])
scrpt = f'''
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_table_0({colnames[0]} TEXT);
    INSERT INTO new_table_0
        SELECT VAR_ID FROM VARIATIONS
                WHERE PARENT_VAR = ''
                AND PART_ID = '{fragments[0]}';
    {joins}
    ALTER TABLE new_table_{len(colnames)-1:d} RENAME TO ASSEMBLY_{assembly}_VARIATIONS;
'''
self._cursor.executescript(scrpt)
```